# ModelForm add the primary ID for an entry in table based on last entry's primary ID

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am creating a signup system. I am using the django's default User's model to store user details, and I am passing its objects into a model named "Employee" where their department, manager and other info is stored. Here is what I have.

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
....
```

forms.py:

```
from users.models import Employee
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class AddNewUserForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


class AddNewEmployeeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = {'department', 'manager', 'total_leaves'}
```

add_new_user.html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_user.as_p }}
    {{ form_emp.as_p }}

       <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
       </div>
  </form>
```

And this is how I'm processing the data in views.py:

```
class AddNewUser(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'LMSAdmin/add_new_user.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_user = AddNewUserForm()
        form_emp = AddNewEmployeeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form_user': form_user, 'form_emp': form_emp})

    def post(self, request):
        form_user = AddNewUserForm(request.POST)
        form_emp = AddNewEmployeeForm(request.POST)

        if form_user.is_valid():
            emp_info = form_emp.save(commit=False)
            emp_info.leaves_taken = 0
            emp_info.user = form_user.save()
            emp_info.save()
            messages.success(request, "Success!")
       else:
           messages.error(request, form_user.errors)
           messages.error(request, form_emp.errors)

       return redirect("add_new_user")
```

The problem is that when the post method is run, it tries to add entries into `Employee` table from the beginning; assuming there are no entries in it. But I have entries in that table and I get the following error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_employee_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.

It gives me this error because I have 6 users in my table already. After this when I try to create the user using this form the 7th time, it works. Is there a way to see how many entries are in the table already and automatically increment it by 1 to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your own primary key field manually

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

and then you could calculate and set the primary key in your saving process. Just get the entry with max. employee_id and increment it by 1. For example like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

# double underscores in employee_id__max
max_employee_id = Employee.objects.all().aggregate(Max('employee_id'))['employee_id__max']
```

Comment: This makes sense. I will try it out but I have one question. Doesn't django forces primary key by default?

Comment: Never mind, I understood what you mean. I don't know why I didn't think of it before. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad, that I could help you! For completeness, if somebody stumbles upon the same problem. "You can create your own primary key field by adding the keyword arg primary_key=True to a field. If you add your own primary key field, the automatic one will not be added."